# How get result with an `if` construction?

Tags: javascript

How get result with an `if` construction?
for example in this case i need true value `->5`

```
function myFunction2() 
{
    return {if (2<4) {5} else {6}};
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid JavaScript, please go through some tutorials covering its syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean to do this:

```
function myFunction2() {
  if (2 < 4) {
    return 5;
  } else {
    return 6;
  }
}
```

Read up: [`return` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: @TraczPlebania I am glad it worked for you. Please upvote and mark this answer as accepted. Here is how to do it, if you dont know it yet: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you're after is just using [the conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
function myFunction2() 
{
    return 2 < 4 ? 5 : 6;
}
```